# I am using powerbuilder version 19. while creating a web proxy. it created a user object named sidesresponse it has properties which are user objects

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using PowerBuilder version 19. While creating a web proxy, I created a user object named  `sidesresponse` which has properties that are also user objects.

`sidesresponse` object is like this

[image: sidesresponse object]

[image: flaggedvalueofstring object]

When I make an assignment like the following

```
inv_responsedata.claimstate = adw_response.object.state[1]
```

it gives no error because in `sidesresponse`, `claimstate` is declared as a string( basic type)

but when i use it like this

```
inv_responsedata.SSN.currentvalue= adw_response.object.ssn[1]
```

it gives a "null value object reference" error because `ssn` is a `flaggedvalueofstring`  object type(user defined)`

it has `currentvalue` property (please see the image)

but why it is not accepting `flaggedvalueofstring` property?

[image]

any clue to the solution is most welcome

Please let me know if you need more details

Thanks
Gopakumar

Answer (score 0):

In your assignment

```
inv_responsedata.SSN.currentvalue = adw_response.object.ssn[1]
```

from the error message, `inv_responsedata.SSN` is null when you try to assign `adw_response.object.ssn[1]` to the `currentvalue` property

You probably need to allocate a new object to `inv_responsedata.SSN` before being able to fill the `currentvalue` property. It is difficult to be affirmative without seing the code.